# Replace array values with another key value using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to replace `array2` available key with `object1` values using javascript.

I have a solution but it's using `foreach` loop, is there any way without using `foreach` loop

```
let object1 = {
   'key1': 'key1 value',
   'key2': 'key2 value',
   'key3': 'key3 value',
   'key4': 'key4 value',
};
let array2 = [key1, key4]
```

**Expected output**

```
let array2 = ['key1 value', 'key2 value']
```

Comment: btw `array1` is a `object` and not a `array`!

Comment: `let array2 = [array1["key1"], array1["key2"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let object1 = {'key1':'key1 value','key2':'key2 value','key3':'key3 value','key4':'key4 value'};
let array2 = ['key1', 'key4']

console.log(array2.reduce((result, key) => (result.push(object1[key]), result), []));
```

#### Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let object1 = {'key1':'key1 value','key2':'key2 value','key3':'key3 value','key4':'key4 value'};
let array2 = ['key1', 'key4']

console.log(array2.map(key => object1[key]));
```

#### Using [`spread ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let object1 = {'key1':'key1 value','key2':'key2 value','key3':'key3 value','key4':'key4 value'};
let array2 = ['key1', 'key4']

console.log([...[object1[array2[0]]], ...[object1[array2[1]]]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map` (or even `forEach`) to loop over to `array2` and then find the values for the `object1` object:

```js
let object1 = {
   'key1': 'key1 value',
   'key2': 'key2 value',
   'key3': 'key3 value',
   'key4': 'key4 value',
};
let array2 = ['key1', 'key4']

const res = array2.map(item => object1[item]);
console.log(res);
```